# Выделение цвета текстом

Tags: c++, mfc

В static text выводится массив. Необходимо выделить цветом определенную его часть. Как это реализовать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ставите richedit с прозрачным фоном и без бордера вот вам и static с разноцветным текстом.

Answer (score 1):

Первое. MFC очень серьезно устарел. Постарайтесь отказаться от его использования.

Второе. Static Text не умеет красить текст частями. Возможно, вам поможет RichEdit в режиме readOnly.

Comment: Знаю, но, к сожалению, от задания избавиться не могу